# O Django não está lendo os arquivos estaticos 'static'

Tags: python, django

Bom, estava tudo certo até um certo momento. Depois não sei o que aconteceu, ou se coloquei algo errado e mais nada está funcionando. O django parou de ler os arquivos estáticos.

Quando tento entrar em qualquer pagina da minha aplicação o seguinte erro aparece:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já verifiquei meu código diversas vezes mas não encontrei nenhum erro, a parte que estão os static é essa:

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/select2.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/select2.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '.confirm-delete', function() {
            $('#confirmDeleteModal').attr('caller-id', $(this).attr('id'));
        });
        $(document).on('click', '#confirmDeleteButtonModal', function() {
            var caller = $('#confirmDeleteButtonModal').closest('.modal').attr('caller-id');
            window.location = $('#'.concat(caller)).attr('href');
        });
        $(function() {
            $('#id_end_date').datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                dayNamesMin: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab"],
                monthNames: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#id_category').select2();
        });
    </script>
```

E no settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
]
```

O que mais me preocupa é que a pagina do admin (http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin), também não está funcionado. Aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meus diretórios:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se puder ajudar a acabar com esse erro, agradeço muito!

Comment: Qual versão do Django você esta usando ?

Comment: versão = (3, 0, 4, 'final', 0)

Comment: Tentou por {% load staticfiles %} em cima do {% load static %} ?

Comment: Sim! ele não aceita o 'staticfiles'

Comment: Utilizar {% load staticfiles %} ao invés de {% load static %}, não funcionou? Muda o nome da tua pasta com os static files, de staticfiles para static. Outra possibilidade, removeste das opções DEFAULT_APPS no settings.py a entrada 'django.contrib.staticfiles',?

Comment: Não, ele da erro ('staticfiles' is not a registered tag library) e fala para utilizar somente 'static'.

Já mudei o nome da pasta para testar antes e também não funcionou, continua os mesmos erros. 

Sim, continua lá essa opção. A unica coisa é que no meu é DJANG_APPS. Mudei para DEFAULT só por desencargo de consciência, mas não mudou nada...

O engraçado é que estava funcionando, não sei se fiz algo que do nada está dando esse erro.

Comment: E é  muito estranho o Admin não estar funcionando também. É como se ele parasse de ler tos os arquivos estaticos...

Comment: Isso esta em ocorrendo em produção ou localmente com `runserver`?

Comment: Local, no runserver mesmo